# Makefile: Setting env var for one build step

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I'm using GNU make and Makefiles. Is it possible to set an environment variable for one build step?

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
VAR:=valueA
step1:
    echo $(VAR)
```

Then, "make step1" will print "valueA".

Is it possible to redefine the env var for one build step?

```
VAR:=valueA
step1:
    echo $(VAR)
step2:
    VAR:=valueB
    echo $(VAR)
```

I want "make step1" to print "valueA", but "make step1" to print "valueB".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, those are *not* environment variables, they're make variables.  It's really important to understand and remember the difference.

Second, yes, you can do this with [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
VAR := valueA
step1:
        echo $(VAR)

step2: VAR := valueB
step2:
        echo $(VAR)
```

If you really do want the value to be present in the child process's environment, you can use make's `export` keyword:

```
export VAR := valueA

step1:
        echo $$VAR
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement MadScientist's answer:
if you actually need to set an *environment* variable because a command you call expects it to be set, you need to do it within the shell commands that are your [recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes.html)s:

```
VAR := value0

all: step1 step2
step1: VAR := value1
step2: VAR := value2

all step1 step2 step3:
        ENVVAR=$(VAR) sh -c 'echo the nested sh for $@ has ENVVAR = $$ENVVAR'
```

Comment: You can also just use the make `export` operation: `export VAR := ...`  Much simpler than running a second shell.

Comment: Hmmm ... very true. Perhaps you can add that to your answer? Then I can delete mine.

Comment: OK, but I think it's pretty clear from the question that haael is not talking about environment variables at all (his rules are using make variables).

Comment: @MadScientist Actually, there is a difference between the shell recipe and _make_'s `export` keyword. Exported target specific variables will also be exported to the shell environment of the recipes of the target's pre-requisites. Personally, I prefer the shell version—more explicit and more private at the same time.

Comment: I think it's hard to understand, unless you're pretty knowledgeable about the shell.  I also don't think that restricting the value of the environment is usually that interesting, since the entirety of the user's environment is already being passed through--who knows what they have there!  But, sure, if it's a real concern it's better to be explicit.  For example I would be more careful with a variable like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (although I'd probably forgo `sh -c` and just use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)' mycommand ...` directly).